# dgrid custom sort with secondary sort column

Tags: dojo, dgrid, dstore

I'm currently using a custom sort function on a dgrid (pasted below).  It doesn't change sorting drastically, just sorts one particular column uniquely and sorts the others case-insensitive. I'd like to add a secondary sort by a column named "scheduled" to be added to the sort when any other column is sorted. I'm just not sure how to go about it.  I've seen how to override the sort to sort by two columns, but not when a custom sort is in play.  The secondary sort would always be there, not matter what other column is clicked.

For reference I'm running dojo 1.10 and dgrid 1.0. Data is coming from a RequestMemory DStore and I'd really rather this sort happen on the grid rather than back at the store level.  Any help would be appreciated.

```js
currGrid.on('dgrid-sort', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var sort = event.sort[0];
  currGrid.set('sort', function (a, b) {
     if (sort.property == "thisField") {
       //special sort for thisField
       if (a[sort.property] !== 'undefined' && typeof a[sort.property] == "string") {
          var colorA =  a[sort.property].split("|");
          var aValue = colorA[0].toLowerCase();
       }
       if (b[sort.property] !== 'undefined' && typeof b[sort.property] == "string") {
          var colorB =  b[sort.property].split("|");
          var  bValue = colorB[0].toLowerCase();
       }
       if (String(aValue) == String(bValue)) {
          var result = 0;
       } else if (dojo.string.trim(aValue) == "") {
          var result = true ? 1 : -1;
       } else if (dojo.string.trim(bValue) == "") {
         var result = true ? -1 : 1;
       } else {
         var result = aValue > bValue ? 1 : -1;
       }
       return result * (sort.descending ? -1 : 1);
     } else {
       //Sort for all other fields same as always (except toLowerCase)
       if (a[sort.property] !== 'undefined' && typeof a[sort.property] == "string") {
          var aValue = a[sort.property].toLowerCase();
       } else {
          var aValue = "";
       }
       if (b[sort.property] !== 'undefined' && typeof b[sort.property] == "string") {
          var bValue = b[sort.property].toLowerCase();
       } else {
          var bValue = "";
       }
       var result = aValue > bValue ? 1 : -1;
       return result * (sort.descending ? -1 : 1);
     }
  });
  currGrid.updateSortArrow(event.sort, true);
});
currGrid.startup();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like below.

```
currGrid.on('dgrid-sort', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var sortSet = [];
    sortSet.push(event.sort[0]);
    sortSet.push({property: "scheduled"});
    currGrid.set('sort', function (a, b) {
        var aValue, bValue, result = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < sortSet.length; i++){
            var sort = sortSet[i];
            if (sort.property == "thisField") {
                //special sort for thisField
                if (a[sort.property] !== 'undefined' && typeof a[sort.property] == "string") {
                    var colorA =  a[sort.property].split("|");
                    aValue = colorA[0].toLowerCase();
                }
                if (b[sort.property] !== 'undefined' && typeof b[sort.property] == "string") {
                    var colorB =  b[sort.property].split("|");
                    bValue = colorB[0].toLowerCase();
                }
                if (String(aValue) == String(bValue)) {
                    result = 0;
                } else if (dojo.string.trim(aValue) == "") {
                    result = true ? 1 : -1;
                } else if (dojo.string.trim(bValue) == "") {
                    result = true ? -1 : 1;
                } else {
                    result = aValue > bValue ? 1 : -1;
                }
                return result * (sort.descending ? -1 : 1);
            } else {
                //Sort for all other fields same as always (except toLowerCase)
                if (a[sort.property] !== 'undefined' && typeof a[sort.property] == "string") {
                    aValue = a[sort.property].toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    aValue = "";
                }
                if (b[sort.property] !== 'undefined' && typeof b[sort.property] == "string") {
                    bValue = b[sort.property].toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    bValue = "";
                }
                //You need this check here 
                if(aValue != bValue){
                    result = aValue > bValue ? 1 : -1;
                    return result * (sort.descending ? -1 : 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    });
    currGrid.updateSortArrow(event.sort, true);
});
currGrid.startup();
```

I have some concerns about your code, the variables `result, aValue and bValue` are all local within the if statement and yet they are being used outside the statement. It could result in wrong results if some other variables are defined with the same name in global space. So I have modified them.

So the second section you needed to check if `aValue == bValue` to return 0.

Comment: @T Kambi Sorry for the delay getting back to you on this, I've just tested this and it works great on the first click to sort any column. However, it reverses the sort of the scheduled column when the other column is sorted the opposite direction. I want scheduled (the secondary sort column) to always be ascending. I tried changing ` sortSet.push({property: "scheduled"});` to sortSet.push({property: "scheduled", descending:false}); and that didn't do it. I probably wasn't clear on this in my original question, but If you can help me work it out, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The schedule sort is always ascending, as we are not setting the descending property for that option. However, it will have second priority over other sort option. If you want the "schedule" to be you first priority then add the schedule sort first and then the other sort in the `sortSet`.

Comment: Yep, you're completely correct.  The column I was clicking had data hidden in it that was causing the sort to go differently than I had planned.  Everything works like it should now.  Thanks @T Kambi